# how to get id by clicking FAB button

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, dialog, floating-action-button

I am displaying a ordered food list. A FloatingActionButton is placed on each food item(productId) at the ordered list, and I want to show a rating alert dialog to let user rate the food after clicking the FloatingActionButton. How do I get each of the productId when user click on the Fab button? Because I need to display the ratings at another food detail page based on the productId. I am just a beginner learning so don't really understand.Thanks

OrderDetailAdapter.java

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public TextView name, quantity, price, discount;
public FloatingActionButton btnRating;

public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
    quantity = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_quantity);
    price = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
    discount = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_discount);
    btnRating = (FloatingActionButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_rating);
}
}

public class OrderDetailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>{

List<Order> myOrders;
private OnRatingButtonClickListener mOnRatingClickListener;

public OrderDetailAdapter(List<Order> myOrders, OnRatingButtonClickListener listener) {
    this.myOrders = myOrders;
    this.mOnRatingClickListener = listener;

}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.order_detail_layout,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}


public interface OnRatingButtonClickListener
{
    void onRatingClick(String productId);
}





@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Order order = myOrders.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(String.format("Name: %s", order.getProductName()));
    holder.quantity.setText(String.format("Quantity: %s", order.getQuantity()));
    holder.price.setText(String.format("Price: %s", order.getPrice()));
    holder.discount.setText(String.format("Discount: %s", order.getDiscount()));

    holder.btnRating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mOnRatingClickListener.onRatingClick(order.getProductId());
        }
    });


}

 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
     return myOrders.size();
}
}
```

OrderDetail.java

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_detail);

    //Firebase
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    foods = database.getReference("Food");
    ratingTbl = database.getReference("Rating");

    //Initialize view
    order_id = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.order_id);
    order_phone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.order_phone);
    order_total = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.order_total);

    lstFoods = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.lstFoods);
    lstFoods.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    lstFoods.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    btnRating = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_rating);





    if(getIntent() != null) {
        order_id_value = getIntent().getStringExtra("OrderId");
        foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra("FoodId");

        //Set value
        order_id.setText(order_id_value);
        order_phone.setText(Common.currentRequest.getPhone());
        order_total.setText(Common.currentRequest.getTotal());

        OrderDetailAdapter adapter = new OrderDetailAdapter(Common.currentRequest.getFoods(),this);
        //OrderDetailAdapter adapter = new OrderDetailAdapter(this);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lstFoods.setAdapter(adapter); }

     @Override
    public void onRatingClick(String productId) {
    btnRating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showRatingDialog();
        }
    });

}

private void showRatingDialog() {
    new AppRatingDialog.Builder()
            .setPositiveButtonText("Submit")
            .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
            .setNoteDescriptions(Arrays.asList("Very Bad","Bad","Quite OK","Very Good","Excellent"))
            .setDefaultRating(1)
            .setTitle("Rate this food")
            .setDescription("Kindly give your ratings and comment")
            .setTitleTextColor(R.color.transparentBlack)
            .setDescriptionTextColor(R.color.transparentBlack)
            .setHint("Please write your comment here...")
            .setHintTextColor(R.color.fbutton_color_midnight_blue)
            .setCommentTextColor(android.R.color.black)
            .setCommentBackgroundColor(android.R.color.white)
            .setWindowAnimation(R.style.RatingDialogFadeAnim)
            .create(OrderDetail.this)
            .show();

}
```

Comment: Your order model should have the product Id

Comment: @VivekMishra yes i have product id in order model. i dont know how to write the code to get the product id in OrderDetailAdapter

Comment: @VivekMishra   i don't know how to complete this line to get the productId : holder.btnRating.....

Comment: setOnClickListener on your button and write order.getProductId

Comment: @VivekMishra i tried this line before: holder.btnRating.setOnClickListener(order.getProductId());
but it shows error. (setOnClickListener in View cannot be applied to java.lang.string)

Answer (score 1):

You can use interface to get the callback of the floating action button on your activity like this :-

In your adapter class

```
public interface OnRatingButtonClickListener{
  void onRatingClick(int productId);
}
```

and you will register this interface object in constructor of your adapter like this:-

```
private OnRatingButtonClickListener mOnRatingClickListener;

public OrderAdapter(OnRatingButtonClickListener listener){
 this.mOnRatingClickListener = listener;
}
```

and in onBindViewHolder, you will do this:-

```
 holder.btnRating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view){
    //interface object
    mOnRatingClickListener.onRatingClick(order.getProductId());
 });
```

and implement this interface in your activity and show your rating dialog.
you have to set the adapter like this :-

```
  OrderAdapter adapter = new OrderAdapter(this);
```

and implements the interface in your activity and you will get the method in your activity like this:-

```
@Override
public onRatingClick(int productId){
  // here you will get the id of your product and you can show dialog here
}
```

If any furthur query,you can ask.

Comment: sorry, i dont understand how to get this:- mOnRatingClickListener.onRatingClick

Comment: you have to create one interface in your adapter class like this:-
public interface OnRatingButtonClickListener{
  void onRatingClick(int productId);
}

Comment: okay, what about this:- mOnRatingClickListener? sorry, because i am new to programming, don't really know how to solve

Comment: I have edited my answer with full implementation, you can check

Comment: in my previous code, i have a parameter at :- 
public OrderDetailAdapter(List<Order> myOrders, OnRatingButtonClickListener listener) {
        this.myOrders = myOrders;
        this.mOnRatingClickListener = listener;
    }
after i added the parameter for onRatingClickListener, it affects my OrderDetail.java adapter

OrderDetailAdapter adapter = new OrderDetailAdapter(Common.currentRequest.getFoods());
//red line here:- error with two parameters in adapter
because this OrderDetail receives request from user after user ordered the food and OrderDetail.java display a list of ordered food

Comment: @Override
public onRatingClick(int productId){
  // here you will get the id of your product and you can show dialog here
}  - is this implemented in the onCreate method?

Comment: You have to pass this keyword in OrderDetailAdapter in your activity like this:-
OrderDetailAdapter adapter = new OrderDetailAdapter(Common.currentRequest.getFoods(),this);

Comment: @Blue77 then you have to implement like this:-
public class OrderDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnRatingButtonClickListener { } and you will see red line after this just press ALT+Insert and implement the method and you will get the method onRatingClick()

Comment: ALT + Enter key instead of ALT+Insert @Blue77

Comment: sorry, still getting a red line for this code :-  OrderDetailAdapter adapter = new OrderDetailAdapter(Common.currentRequest.getFoods(),this);

Comment: yeah you have to implement the interface in your activity like this :-
 public class OrderDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnRatingButtonClickListener{
}

Comment: is it due to Request class? because once order is placed will send a request and request class will get the current request from user to display the food list, so from the food list, i need to add a rating button for each food

Comment: okay, i've tried with the codes, however still facing nullpointerexception on the FAB button , null at this code :-  mOnRatingClickListener.onRatingClick(order.getProductId());

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: i've edited my code to the current one, it have error in line `btnRating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`  and  `mOnRatingClickListener.onRatingClick(order.getProductId());`

Comment: it should be holder.btnRating.setOnClickListener() in onBindViewHolder. I have specified this in my edited code above

Comment: and  tell me what is the type of product id? Is it a String or int ?

Comment: i put as String in my model for the productId, yea i have typed `holder.btnRating.setOnClickListener()` in onBindViewHolder, but have error in `btnRating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` at `public void onRatingClick(String productId)`, showing nullPointerException