# Create dynamic intent in onBindViewHolder (RecyclerView Adapter)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to figure out a smarter way of creating dynamic intents in my `onBindViewHolder`.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.ivIntroList.setImageResource(mIntroListImages.get(position));
        viewHolder.tvIntroList.setText(mIntroListNames.get(position));

        viewHolder.ivIntroList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        Intent intentHero = new Intent(mContext,heroActivity.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(intentHero);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent intentItem = new Intent(mContext,itemActivity.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(intentItem);
                        break;
                         .
                         .
                         .
                     case n:
                       break

                }

            }
        });
```

What is a smarter way of creating my intents with the usage of position?
I know that the `switch` cannot be the smartest solution.

What is important to know is that I want to use mIntroListNames since we have there hero, item, spell ... etc whereas the activites are all called heroActivity, itemActivity, spellActivity...

That is why I think there should be a smarter solution!

Comment: You should use interface to get the callback in your activity to fire the Intent and try not to use context in your adapter

Comment: I think I will try that.. any hints on how to use a callback? :s

Comment: You can see my answer :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52531227/how-to-get-id-by-clicking-fab-button/52531419#52531419 . If any query,you can ask

Answer (score 1):

Try to refer this sample code hope it will help:
By using intent.put extra we can dynamically update a single activity with required data:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(backadapter.exViewHolder holder, final int position){
    holder.exname.setText(exList.get(position).name);
    holder.exlogo.setImageResource(exList.get(position).logoId);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (position == 0 ){
                Intent i1=new Intent(context,abdetails.class);
                i1.putExtra("img",R.drawable.twobarpullups);
                i1.putExtra("text",R.string.crunches);
                context.startActivity(i1);


            }
            if (position == 1) {
                Intent i1=new Intent(context,abdetails.class);
                i1.putExtra("img",R.drawable.highpulleyrowgif);
                i1.putExtra("text",R.string.declinecrunch);
                context.startActivity(i1);


            }
            if (position == 2) {
                Intent i1=new Intent(context,abdetails.class);
                i1.putExtra("img",R.drawable.chinupsgif);
                i1.putExtra("text",R.string.dumsidebend);
                context.startActivity(i1);

            }
            if (position == 3) {
                Intent i1=new Intent(context,abdetails.class);
                i1.putExtra("img",R.drawable.curlbaronearmrow);
                i1.putExtra("text",R.string.hanglegraise);
                context.startActivity(i1);
            }
            if (position == 4) {
                Intent i1=new Intent(context,abdetails.class);
                i1.putExtra("img",R.drawable.hangdumrowgif);
                i1.putExtra("text",R.string.inclineleg);
                context.startActivity(i1);
            }
            if (position == 5) {
                Intent i1=new Intent(context,abdetails.class);
                i1.putExtra("img",R.drawable.ropechingif);
                i1.putExtra("text",R.string.legraise);
                context.startActivity(i1);
            }
            if (position == 6) {
                Intent i1=new Intent(context,abdetails.class);
                i1.putExtra("img",R.drawable.deadliftgif);
                i1.putExtra("text",R.string.flatbenchlyingleg);
                context.startActivity(i1);
            }
            if (position == 7) {
                Intent i1=new Intent(context,abdetails.class);
                i1.putExtra("img",R.drawable.seatedrowsgif);
                i1.putExtra("text",R.string.jackknife);
                context.startActivity(i1);
            }
            if (position == 8) {
                Intent i1=new Intent(context,abdetails.class);
                i1.putExtra("img",R.drawable.barbentoverrowgif);
                i1.putExtra("text",R.string.jackknife);
                context.startActivity(i1);
            }
            if (position == 9) {
                Intent i1=new Intent(context,abdetails.class);
                i1.putExtra("img",R.drawable.bentoverreversegripgif);
                i1.putExtra("text",R.string.twisthip);
                context.startActivity(i1);
            }
            if (position == 10) {
                Intent i1=new Intent(context,abdetails.class);
                i1.putExtra("img",R.drawable.tbarrowsgif);
                i1.putExtra("text",R.string.weightcrunch);
                context.startActivity(i1);
            }
            if (position == 11) {
                Intent i1=new Intent(context,abdetails.class);
                i1.putExtra("img",R.drawable.straigharmpulldowngif);
                i1.putExtra("text",R.string.plank);
                context.startActivity(i1);
            }



        }
    });

}
```

code for main class of targeted activity:

```
public class abdetails extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_abdetails);
    GifImageView gifImageView;
    gifImageView=findViewById(R.id.gifview);
    Intent i1=getIntent();

    TextView tv;


    tv = findViewById(R.id.exdesc);
    tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    gifImageView.setBackgroundResource(i1.getIntExtra("img",0));
    tv.setText(i1.getIntExtra("text",0));

    }
```

Comment: Yes putExtra could be useful here.
Thanks I know how to use that.

Comment: Well I think i deleted half of my comment from yesterday.

Anyway I edited my main post accordingly to explain my main issue better.